# How to select all elements greater than a given values in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv that is read by my python code and a dataframe is created using pandas.

CSV file is in following format

```
1     1.0
2     99.0
3     20.0
7     63
```

My code calculates the percentile and wants to find all rows that have the value in 2nd column greater than 60.

```
df = pd.read_csv(io.BytesIO(body), error_bad_lines=False, header=None, encoding='latin1', sep=',')

percentile = df.iloc[:, 1:2].quantile(0.99)  # Selecting 2nd column and calculating percentile

criteria = df[df.iloc[:, 1:2] >= 60.0]
```

While my percentile code works fine, criteria to find all rows that have column 2's value greater than 60 returns

```
NaN     NaN
NaN     NaN
NaN     NaN
NaN     NaN
```

Can you please help me find the error.

Comment: What is `frame`? If I replace `frame` with `df` in the third row of your code everything basically works here...

Comment: I don't know whether this is what you want, but you can replace the column indices `1:2` by `1`: `criteria = frame[frame.iloc[:, 1] >= 60.0]`.

Comment: @applesoup has the answer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just correct the condition inside criteria. Being the second column "1" you should write  df.iloc[:,1].
Example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
b =np.array([[1,2,3,7], [1,99,20,63] ])

df = pd.DataFrame(b.T) #just creating the dataframe


criteria = df[ df.iloc[:,1]>= 60 ]     
print(criteria)
```

Why?
It seems like the cause resides inside the definition type of the condition. Let's inspect

Case 1:

```
type( df.iloc[:,1]>= 60 )
```

Returns *pandas.core.series.Series*,
so it gives

```
 df[ df.iloc[:,1]>= 60 ]

 #out:
   0   1
1  2  99
3  7  63
```

Case2:

```
type( df.iloc[:,1:2]>= 60 )
```

Returns a  *pandas.core.frame.DataFrame*
, and gives

```
df[ df.iloc[:,1:2]>= 60 ]

#out:
    0     1
0 NaN   NaN
1 NaN  99.0
2 NaN   NaN
3 NaN  63.0
```

Therefore I think it changes the way the index is processed.
Always keep in mind that **3 is a scalar, and 3:4 is a array**.

For more info is always good to take a look at the official doc [Pandas indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html)

Comment: What if I want to make this comparison between the Int() of each element in my data frame and a given number?

Comment: Maybe you're looking for [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) or [apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html)

Answer (score 2):

Your indexing a bit off, since you only have two columns `[0, 1]` and you are interested in selecting just the one with index `1`. As `@applesoup` mentioned the following is just enough:

```
criteria = df[df.iloc[:, 1] >= 60.0]
```

However, I would consider naming columns and just referencing based on name. This will allow you to avoid any mistakes in case your `df` structure changes, e.g.:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 7], 'b': [1.0, 99.0, 20.0, 63.]})

criteria = df[df['b'] >= 60.0]
```

Answer (score 2):

People here seem to be more interested in coming up with alternative solutions instead of digging into his code in order to find out what's really wrong. I will adopt a diametrically opposed strategy!

The problem with your code is that you are indexing your DataFrame `df` by another DataFrame. Why? Because you use `slices` instead of integer indexing.

```
df.iloc[:, 1:2] >= 60.0 # Return a DataFrame with one boolean column
df.iloc[:, 1] >= 60.0 # Return a Series
df.iloc[:, [1]] >= 60.0 # Return a DataFrame with one boolean column
```

So correct your code by using :

```
criteria = df[df.iloc[:, 1] >= 60.0] # Dont slice !
```